# Link between 3 tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables, consultant, skill and consultant_skill. I'm looking all the skills from consultant 1.

How can i create a relationship betwwen three with select from and where?

thank you

SQL - ORACLE DATABASE

```
CREATE TABLE consultant
(c_id NUMBER(6),
c_last VARCHAR2(20),
c_first VARCHAR2(20),
c_mi CHAR(1),
c_add VARCHAR2(30),
c_city VARCHAR2(20),
c_state CHAR(2),
c_zip VARCHAR2(10),
c_phone VARCHAR2(15),
c_email VARCHAR2(30), 
CONSTRAINT consultant_c_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (c_id));

CREATE TABLE skill
(skill_id NUMBER(3),
skill_description VARCHAR2(50),
CONSTRAINT skill_skill_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (skill_id));

CREATE TABLE consultant_skill
(c_id NUMBER(6),
skill_id NUMBER(3),
certification VARCHAR2(8),
CONSTRAINT consultant_skill_pk PRIMARY KEY (c_id, skill_id),
CONSTRAINT consultant_skill_c_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES consultant(c_id),
CONSTRAINT consultant_skill_skill_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (skill_id) REFERENCES skill(skill_id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the usual way is to use PK to JOIN against FK as below:

```
select
  *
from
  consultant
  join
  consultant_skill
    on consultant.c_id = consultant_skill.c_id
  join
  skill
    on consultant_skill.skill_id = skill.skill_id
```

As a rule of thumb, check if there are `n-1` joins for `n` tables to avoid cartesian joins.

Comment: I have a question, usually I use select to chose the columns i want to show in the result. I tried to change the * but it's not working

Comment: @Caroleb: What did you change in the query and where and what error are you getting? You might want to post another question with these details.

Comment: I'm just wondering, from the query you gave me, how do I select the columns i want to show?

Comment: @Caroleb If you have columns that are in multiple tables, then you need to prefix them with the table name. For example `skill_id` is in both `consultant` and `consultant_skill` then you need to use `consultant.skill_id` to avoid an "ambiguous column" error from Oracle

Comment: @Caroleb: You just put the names of the columns you want to show after the `SELECT` separated by comma. Also note my other comment about columns present in multiple tables. If you are still unsuccessful, post the ORA error.